# Stamp rotated text using itext7 in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext7

I'm trying to convert some itextsharp code to use itext7 which stamps text on each page of a pdf at rotate 90 degrees. Unfortunately all the examples I can find are in c# and while I can use an online translator I'm having difficulties with this one.

The below code stamps my text on at the specified coords on each page of a given pdf:

```
Shared Sub itext7_stamp_text_on_pdf(mypdfname As String, myfoldername As String)


        Dim src As String = myfoldername & "\" & mypdfname
        Dim dest As String = myfoldername & "\Stamped " & mypdfname

        Dim pdfDoc As PdfDocument = New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(src), New PdfWriter(dest))
        Dim document As Document = New Document(pdfDoc)
        Dim canvas As PdfCanvas
        Dim n As Integer = pdfDoc.GetNumberOfPages()

        For i = 1 To n

            Dim page As PdfPage = pdfDoc.GetPage(i)
            canvas = New PdfCanvas(page)
                  
            With canvas
                .SetFontAndSize(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(StandardFonts.HELVETICA), 12)
                .BeginText()

                .MoveText(100, 100)
                .ShowText("SAMPLE TEXT 100,100")

                .EndText()

            End With

        Next

        pdfDoc.Close()

    End Sub
```

... but I can't see a way of rotating it to 90 degrees.

There's an example here if you use a paragraph:

https://kb.itextpdf.com/home/it7kb/examples/itext-7-building-blocks-chapter-2-rootelement-examples#iText7BuildingBlocksChapter2:RootElementexamples-c02e14_showtextaligned

... but I can't seem to translate this to vb.net. I can specify where the errors I get are, but I thought I'd be better asking this general question first in case there's a way to do this without using a paragraph.

Can anyone help please?

Thanks!

Comment: edit - posted as answer

Answer (score 0):

Well, after some more digging this code seems to work OK on the rotation part:

```
Dim pdf As New PdfDocument(New PdfReader(inpdf), New PdfWriter(outpdf))  

    Dim document As New Document(pdf)

    document.ShowTextAligned("This is some test text", 400, 750, TextAlignment.CENTER, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE, 0.5F * CSng(Math.PI))

    document.Close()

    End Sub
```

.... but it gets hidden behind existing content, so I need a way to make sure it's set to over content.